# Prove that one of $a$, $b$, or $c$ is divisible by 5, all of which are relatively prime, and such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have a somewhat curious problem. Suppose $a$, $b$, and $c$ are three relatively prime integers such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Use the fact that the number $st(t^4-s^4) \equiv 0 \hspace{3pt} (\textrm{mod}\ 5)$ to show that one of these three numbers also must be divisible by 5.

I've tried multiplying both sides of the equation by $(a^2-b^2)ab$, only to eventually derive the expression $c^2(b^2-a^2) \equiv 0$, which remains frustratingly oblique. I'm stuck!

Any nudges in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Squares are only $0,1$ or $-1\bmod 5$. But if you don't allow $0\bmod 5$ then $a^2+b^2$ can only be $2,-2$ or $0\bmod 5$. Of course the first two options won't give you another square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $5\not\mid abc$, then $a^4\equiv b^4\equiv c^4\equiv1$ mod $5$. Now if $c^2=a^2+b^2$ with $5\not\mid abc$, then

$$1\equiv c^4\equiv(a^2+b^2)^2=a^4+2a^2b^2+b^4\equiv1+2a^2b^2+1\mod 5$$

from which it follows that $2a^2b^2\equiv-1$ mod $5$. But this implies

$$4\equiv4a^4b^4=(2a^2b^2)^2\equiv(-1)^2=1\mod 5$$

which is a contradiction. Hence $c^2=a^2+b^2$ implies $5\mid abc$

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was quick and easy to follow. Have a lovely rest of your afternoon!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $bc$ is not a multiple of $5$.

Then, from the premise

$(c^4 - b^4) = (c^2 - b^2)(c^2 + b^2)$ is a multiple of 5.

If $(c^2 - b^2) = a^2$ is a multiple of 5, then you are done.

Assume not.

Since it is assumed that neither $b$ nor $c$ is a multiple of 5, you know that $b^2 \equiv \pm 1\pmod{5}$ and $c^2 \equiv \pm 1\pmod{5}.$

Since it is being assumed that $(c^2 + b^2)$ is a multiple of $5$, then either $c^2 \equiv 1\pmod{5}$ and $b^2 \equiv -1\pmod{5}$, or vice versa.

The first possibility above implies that $a^2 \equiv 2\pmod{5}$ and the second possibility implies that $a^2 \equiv 3\pmod{5}$.

Both of the above hypothetical cases are impossible, because, for any integer $a$, $a^2$ must be congruent, $\pmod{5}$ to either $0,1,$ or $-1$.